# Is there a real proof that Stern-Gerlach Interferometer is behaving like it wasn't there, exactly the same spin direction at output as input?

Tags: quantum-spin

Have you heard of, know or performed an experiment with a Stern-Gerlach Interferometer (SGI) that would prove that it is really behaving like it wasn't there. We obtained exactly the same spin orientation at output as it was at input, no matter the apparatus orientation.
From what I can find there is big trouble in performing Stern-Gerlach inteferometer itself, not even talking a bout a sequential experiment with it.

This case bothers me the most. I'm very skeptical about spooky theories and want to know what is experimental base on that.

If possible a link to a trusted source would be super nice.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to review the SGI literature for you. What articles have you looked at? One I randomly pulled up seemed quite clear on what was done, how it was done, and that the effect is real. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: @JonCuster I hoped a person related to domain will say: Yes, I thought about that years ago, this is one of my favorite mysteries, I remember several experiments where practice match theory exactly, no doubts. Here is one randomly pulled article link.

Comment: I've been thinking about it for two weeks, hours of googling were ending in just theories and math, maybe I don't know the right keywords, then I found and old work that SGI is impossible, then I found a new one that they did it but  they din't test it sequentially, then I found one older that kind like performed something but wasn't convincing.Then I decided to ask a question.

Comment: How about https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00325378